# Save If Modified Method

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to write a SaveIfModified method, and it is expected to work with WinForms, in a way that whenever I am editing a file, and if i close it in between without saving it, it should prompt a dialog box, mentioning, "data has been updated, are u sure u want to close without saving?".
This method surely works for that, but, its prompting the same dialog if there aren't any changes or modifications made.
I am not able to catch why is this happening?

```
  private bool SaveIfModified()
    {
        //    if (!Modified) //don't do anything
        //      return true;

        if (Modified)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("The current file has been Updated. Do you want to Save Changes?", "Do you want to Save Changes", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                if (FileName != null)
                {
                    return WriteFile(FileName);
                }
                else
                {
                    SaveFileDialog.FileName = FileName;
                    if (SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                        return WriteFile(SaveFileDialog.FileName);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (result == DialogResult.No)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else // DialogResult.Cancel i.e "fine, no need to save"
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: How is `Modified` implemented? And did you remember to reset it so that it doesn't keep the previous value (i.e. if you only set it to true when there's a change, and then don't reset it to false after saving - it'll still be true the next time even if there was no additional change)?

Comment: Modified is set to true initially (Bool Modified = true;)

Comment: The form includes, 'File  Tab' in 'Menu Bar' which contains, Open, Close, Edit etc

Comment: Yes. But do you reset it to `false`? (See my edit to my previous comment. Reload the page).

Comment: @ispiro So its implemented, in Open, (as in between editing someone clicks 'Open' ), in Edit , in Exit and in close.

Comment: @ispiro I dont think i did the reset.

Comment: @ispiro  I editied the last 'else' statement and made it: else
            {
                Modified = false;
                return false;
            }    //but still its showing the same error, please can you help me with this, as what i am thinking, is that i am covering all conditions

Comment: No. That won't work. Remember that that code will only run when `Modified = false` anyway. You need to have `Modified = false` right after ***saving***. Because that means: `Since this save there have not been (yet) any changes.`.

Comment: You need to provide the logic of how Modified is marked true. Basically i think you are either defaulting to true or forgetting to reset it to false afterwards.

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer yeah i have declared it as:     
protected bool Modified=true;

Answer (score 0):

Remember to reset it so that it doesn't keep the previous value.

If you only set it to `true` when there's a change, and then don't reset it to `false` after saving - it'll still be true the next time even if there was no additional change.

Generally, it has to start off as `false`. Be changed to `true` when there's a change. And changed to `false` after a save.